# Merge Multiple Dataframes Pandas and drop duplicate row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Looking for a way to merge a list of Pandas dataframes for the following effect.
Multiple dataframes as shown below, df1 - df3, combined into new_df.

df1:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category | A | B | C |
| Lunch | 17 | 11 | 6 |

df2:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category | A | B | C |
| Dinner | 1 | 3 | 5 |

df3:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category | A | B | C |
| Snacks | 11 | 1 | 6 |

new_df:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category | A | B | C |
| Lunch | 17 | 11 | 6 |
| Dinner | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| Snacks | 11 | 1 | 6 |

I have tried:

```
pdList = [df1,df2,df3]
new_df = pd.concat(pdList)
```

But it doesnt merge the Category A B C entries as it is concatenation.
Thus Category A B C is kept from every dataframe. It is required once, as the figures relate to the category letter above it.
Is there a way to use merge on multiple dfs and get this effect?

Comment: Are you trying to use your row index, as the key beetween the dataframes?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 I edited the question to make it easier to visualise. So Category, Snacks, Lunch, Dinner were originally column headers and the dataframes get transposed to how you see now. I have tried the code above. I could try merge 1 by 1 but was hoping there was a quicker way.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem here my dude, is that you are trying to concatenate based on your category index. Which is something totally unnecessary since you have it in all of your dfs

Just drop the category column. On your dfs objects, and mantain it in at least one

```
list_df = [#dfs you want to drop it in]
pdList = []
for i in list_df:
    pdList.append(i.drop('Category',axis = 0,inplace = True))
pdList.append(#Df you want to keep the category row)
```

After this a simple, pd.concat([your_df])